# How to scrape multi-line java logs with promtail?

Tags: multiline, grafana-loki

1. Here is som java logs

```
2020-08-21 19:55:44-[audit]-INFO[http-nio-8001-exec-10]BeetlsqlDebugInterceptor.println(20) |
┏━━━━━ Debug [conclusionOperator.selectConclusionOperator] ━━━
┣ SQL：   select id,create_time,update_time from conclusion_operator where id=?
┣ PARAMETERS：         [751]
┣ POSITION：                org.aaaa.audit.controller.MailController.getElecMail(MailController.java:584)
┣ TIME：                        3ms
┣ RESULT：                   [2]
┗━━━━━ Debug [conclusionOperator.selectConclusionOperator] ━━━
```

This 8 lines is one log event actrully, how to config promtail to scrape this lines as one log event? prefer to your pipeline_stages ! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score -1):

It is not possible when using Promtail <= 2.1 . Either you use a framework that posts directly to loki like @nehaev or you have to upgrade to Loki 2.2

The workaround for Loki < 2.2 is to encode your multi line log statement in json or [logfmt](https://brandur.org/logfmt) (preferably the later, as it is better readable without parsing). The new lines are escaped by `\n` in these encodings and for Promtail its still a single line.

you would then have a log line like

```
time="2020-08-21 19:55:44" msg="line1\nline2\nline3" level=INFO logger=audit ...
```

you can then find and parse it with the following query

```
{app="someApp"} |= "..." | logfmt
```

Grafana will then parse all the fields in the log line like `level=INFO` additionally it will deescape the message to

```
line1
line2
line3
```

The nice thing about this approach is you cann add meta information like a correlation id, transaction id, tenant/customer id that is easy to find but still parsable by Grafana.

Comment: I think you should mention that grafana will "deescape" when you click the button "Remove escaping" next to the misleading comment "Your logs might have incorrectly escaped content"

Comment: thats a cool new feature that did not exist back in the good old time (few months ago) :-)

Answer (score -2):

If you use Logback as your logging framework, consider switching to an appender that writes directly to Loki: https://github.com/loki4j/loki-logback-appender (disclosure: I'm an author of it).

Unlike promtail, it works with original Logback's log events and doesn't need to parse anything. So no issues with multiline strings, custom labels, etc.

Comment: Do not do this. This breaks the 12 factor apps (https://12factor.net/) best practices. Basically logging shouldn't be a responsibility of the application itself. Applications should only log to standard output and other services should manage the challenge of writing to a centralized logging system. Apps should focus on the business, not infrastructure level concerns.

Comment: @AFP_555 it's a technical question, not religious. Always there are pros and cons. Not everybody is happy with formatting data to string with one tool and then parsing with another loosing some info along the way (multilines, dynamic labels). Not everybody is happy with adding one more software beast to their zoo with all the configuration and maintenance efforts it takes. Please let people be pragmatic and decide by themselves what's the better fit for their purposes.

Comment: The problem is that this looks attractive from a developer's perspective, but it has downsides people wouldn't know about since they are asking this question. But I do agree, all options should be presented and evaluated. By warning them about the 12 factor apps best practices they can go and do a bit of research. I can no longer edit my comment to change my wording.